# Why does Rinzler (Tron) purr?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

Why does Rinzler (Tron) purr. Is it because of the damage that he sustained when Clu attacked him?

Comment: Maybe it's because he wants his dinner.

Comment: @Richard,LOL, maybe!

Comment: I'm not sure I'd classify that sound as a purr (I have a couple cats). It sounds more like the sound design was for something like a low mechanical growl. It serves the purpose of alerting the audience and characters to Rinzler's threat even if he isn't on screen. It also enhances his "inhuman" presence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only potential clue comes when Tron falls into the sea after betraying CLU (around 1:05 in the clip below). The sound is very distinct when he passes the camera and then stops with the color change from red(CLU) to white(user)

I'd say that the purring at the very least represents the control CLU has over him.

Answer (score 5):

The sound Rinzler makes is the same sound a corrupted and physically damaged hard disk drive will make when the stylus skids over a damaged sector. Yet another subtle clue that the poor fellow isn't quite operating correctly. In other words, he's producing a Click of Death.

Comment: I've seen a PC go down because of a damaged HDD before. I remember the sound it made.